# How i can Do dynamic checkboxes for java jsp?

Tags: javascript, checkbox

i need to do six checkboxes for one image , and this image need to change if one or more checkboxes is cheked , how i can do it? please help me , i attach my code.

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="img/fotodiente/1.jpg" width="78" height="107" alt="1" id="diente1" onclick="changeImage1()"/>
        
        <form name="form1" onsubmit="checkBoxValidation()">
            <p><input type="checkbox" name="chbdiente1" value="1"/>Vestibular</p>
            <p><input type="checkbox" name="chbdiente1" value="2"/>Mesial</p>
            <p><input type="checkbox" name="chbdiente1" value="3"/>Oclusal</p>
            <p><input type="checkbox" name="chbdiente1" value="4"/>Distal</p>
            <p><input type="checkbox" name="chbdiente1" value="5"/>Palatino</p>
            <p><input type="checkbox" name="chbdiente1" value="6"/>Lingual</p>
            <p><input type="submit" value="submit"/>
        </form>
        <%String chbdiente1[] = request.getParameterValues("chbdiente1");
            if (chbdiente1 != null) {%>
        <script>
            function changeImage1() {
                var image = document.getElementById('diente1');

                image.src = "img/fotodiente/1.1.jpg";
            }
            ;
        </script>
        <ul><%for (int i = 0; i < chbdiente1.length; i++) {%>
            <li><%=chbdiente1[i]%></li><%}%>
        </ul><%}%>
    </body>
</html>
```

i have this code and send me the value of selected checkboxes , but the image not change. help please. thanks

Comment: You need to call changeImage1 from a click or change handler tied to the checkboxes, not a click handler tied to the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change the image after click of checkboxes you need to call changeImage1() into onchange or onclick method of checkbox.

Example:

```
<script>
    $('document').ready(function(){
       $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
           changeImage1();
       });


    });

    function changeImage1() {
           var image = document.getElementById('diente1');
           image.src = "img/fotodiente/1.1.jpg";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, the code works perfect, now based on the same code I will try to make the image change when there are 1 of the 6 values ​​marked and it stays normal if there is not one marked and I will share it if it serves you Someone else :) thank you very much

Comment: Thanks you too. Pleasure to have helped you.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function changeImage1() {

    var image = document.getElementById('diente1');
    var checkboxes = document.getElementById("form1");
    var cont = 0;

    try {
        for (var x = 0; x < checkboxes.length; x++) {
            if (checkboxes[x].checked) {
                cont = cont + 1;
            }
        }
    } catch (e) {

    }
    try {
        if (cont > 0) {
            image.src = "img/fotodiente/1.1.jpg";
            d1 = 2;
            array.push("Pieza 1");
            var chb2 = document.getElementsByName("form1");
        } else if (cont === 0) {
            image.src = "img/fotodiente/1.jpg";
            d1 = 1;
            array.splice(1, 1);
        }
    } catch (e) {

    }
}
;
```

```html
 <img src="img/fotodiente/1.jpg" class="item_thumb" width="78" height="107" alt="1" id="diente1" onclick="changeImage1()"/>

                <form id="form1" method="post" action="">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="chbdiente1" value="1" onclick="changeImage1();" /><label>Vestibular</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="chbdiente1" value="2" onclick="changeImage1();" /><label>Mesial</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="chbdiente1" value="3" onclick="changeImage1();" /><label>Oclusal</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="chbdiente1" value="4" onclick="changeImage1();" /><label>Distal</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="chbdiente1" value="5" onclick="changeImage1();" /><label>Palatino</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="chbdiente1" value="6" onclick="changeImage1();" /><label>Lingual</label>
                    <input type="button" name="Submit" value="Contar" hidden="">
                </form>
```

Well, this changes the image when there are 1 or more checkboxes clicked, if all the checkboxes are unchecked the image returns to the first one.
I hope also I can help others and thanks